# finding a string from 2 arraylists

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I'm having some trouble with my code. I'm making a bilingual translator but what i don't understand is how to look up a string from one array list and grab its translated form from another array list. I'm going to have 100 words, so 200 total. I'm just confused on that part.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String enterTheWord;
        String yes = "yes";
        String Yes = "Yes";
        String enterChoice;

        ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>(100);
        dictionary.add("gracias");

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Translator!");
        System.out.println("Please be wary that this is an English to Spanish Translator!");
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
        enterChoice = keyboard.next();

        if ( enterChoice.equals(yes))
        {
            System.out.print("What word do you wish to translate? " );
            enterTheWord = keyboard.next();
        }
        else if (enterChoice.equals(Yes))
        {
            System.out.print("What word do you wish to translate? " );
            enterTheWord = keyboard.next();
        }
        else
            System.out.print("");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try using atleast `HashMap` for maintaining the translation data.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String enterTheWord = null;
        String enterChoice;

        Map<String, String> translationMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        translationMap.put("gracious", "gracioso"); // translation map for english as key and spanish as value.

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Translator!");
        System.out.println("Please be wary that this is an English to Spanish Translator!");
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue?");
        enterChoice = keyboard.next();

        if (enterChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
            System.out.print("What word do you wish to translate? ");
            enterTheWord = keyboard.next(); // get english text
        }

        System.out.println(translationMap.get(enterTheWord));
    }
```

**output**

```
Welcome to the Translator!
Please be wary that this is an English to Spanish Translator!
Do you wish to continue?
yes
What word do you wish to translate? gracious
gracioso
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use two [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)(s). Something like,

```
Map<String, String> english = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> spanish = new HashMap<>();
english.put("Hello", "Hola");
english.put("Hola", "Hello");

System.out.printf("%s in English is %s in Spanish%n", "Hello", 
    english.get("Hello"));
```

Or, use a [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) because you can then externalize the `String`(s) and mappings. Also, you can add more languages without modifying code.